# Android: leaked IntentReceiver although no BroadCast receiver used

Tags: android

My app works just fine on an actual device, but when I use an emulator, I am getting the leaked `IntentReceiver` error.
I DID NOT use any broadcast receiver, the only receiver declared in my manifest is the `FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver` and some other Firebase ID receiver which I believe does not need to be unregistered.
Help is appreciated
Here is the error:

```
 Service com.android.providers.media.MtpService has leaked IntentReceiver android.mtp.MtpDatabase$1@9399bf3 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                               android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.android.providers.media.MtpService has leaked IntentReceiver android.mtp.MtpDatabase$1@9399bf3 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:922)
                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:723)
                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1158)
                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1138)
                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1132)
                                                   at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:554)
                                                   at android.mtp.MtpDatabase.setServer(MtpDatabase.java:253)
                                                   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.manageServiceLocked(MtpService.java:359)
                                                   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.access$1700(MtpService.java:57)
                                                   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService$MtpMsgHandler.doStartMtpServer(MtpService.java:338)
                                                   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService$MtpMsgHandler.handleMessage(MtpService.java:272)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: are you closing the MTP device you're using before releasing the context that's using it ?

It seems like the MTP device object is the one that registered the receiver and it should be closed so that it does release its receiver.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with MTP, does that mean the device transferring images from the computer to the emulator? The app does have lots of images. If that's the case how do I solve it? I have no idea what type of receiver it is

Comment: I'm not familiar with it too, but this is where you should start looking
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/mtp/MtpDevice.html